# Open Source solution for sharing screenshots

Tags: open-source, screenshot, sharing

I am searching for an open source solution to take screenshots and upload them to my website. I know of many services for it, but they upload images to their own sites. If I give this link to my friends, the page contains a lot of ads.

In an ideal case, I want to find software (Windows/Mac), which will take a screenshot with a keyboard shortcut. It should also include an option to upload this screenshot to an FTP server and then open URL with this image. Also, it would be cool if I can setup several FTP servers and then chose one of them.

I made my solution for Windows using Greenshot + WinSCP + own utility, but I want it for Mac too. Greenshot does not work under Mac.

Comment: Related question for GNU/Linux: [Screen capture tool with uploading to a server for Ubuntu?](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/32116/60)