# Screen capture tool with uploading to a server for Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, screen-recording, screenshot, sharing

I'm using Ubuntu and I'm looking for a tool that can make a screenshot, upload it to a server and give me a link.

There are tons of similar programs for other operating systems. For example:

- http://clip2net.com/en/
- http://monosnap.com/

But they both don't have a Linux version. The only thing I've found for Ubuntu is http://joxi.net/ but it's buggy as hell, doesn't support a second monitor and simply crashes every few hours, so I'm looking for an alternative.

I'm also looking for a software to capture a video of my desktop and upload it to a server for easier sharing. Bonus points if both those functions (screenshot + video) are in the same program.

Answer (score 8):

You might wish to take a look at **[Shutter](http://shutter-project.org/)** – which offers this and more:

[image: Shutter upload] [image: Shutter upload] [image: Shutter upload targets] [image: Imgur upload URLs]
<sup>*Shutter* upload screenshots (click images for larger variants)</sup>

As the screenshots show, *Shutter* allows you uploading to many public image hosters, and you can even upload to your own FTP server if you wish to. After a successful upload, it gives you the URL(s) for the uploaded image (see 4<sup>th</sup> screenshot).

You can find *Shutter* in the Ubuntu repositories, or use the PPA listed at the [Shutter homepage](http://shutter-project.org/). For additional details, also see [Can we directly upload and share screenshots?](https://askubuntu.com/q/676269/68291) on our *AskUbuntu* sister site.

Answer (score 3):

I made a client like that for both Windows and Linux. It is very minimalist (but does what it is designed for) and unfortunately doesn't support video uploads.

You can download the binaries here: [OwnShot Releases on Github](https://github.com/ardaozkal/ownshot/releases).

It takes a bit long to install [as specified here](https://github.com/ardaozkal/ownshot/wiki/How-to-use:-Linux), but it shouldn't take more than 15 minutes after mono is installed.

What this has over shutter is that shutter is way too complex. With this, I can just press a few buttons and my image will be uploaded to my server, however shutter requires me to handpick the name etc.

It uploads to the FTP server of your choice, and puts the URL into your clipboard (the URL prefix must be configured).

DISCLAIMER: This is a completely free software developed by me.

Comment: Does it require me to use my own server?

Comment: @VictorMarchuk yep, but please let me know if you want me to add other services.

Comment: @ardaozkal imgur is the cleanest service to add imo. direct links without hassle and a decent (ish) API